# PHP to display id of video from YouTube URL

Tags: php, regex

I am currently trying to retrieve YouTube video IDs through url. I created a function `getYoutubeVideoID` that strips `$url` and finds the `$sVideoID`. The Problem is that when i echo the variable i get an empty value of $sVideoID. How come i am getting no value result for `$sVideoID` if i am assigning it the video ID?

```
<?php

if($_POST)
{

$url     = $_POST['yurl'];

function getYoutubeVideoID($url) {
    $sVideoID = preg_replace('~https?://(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be/| youtube\.com\S*[^\w\-\s])([\w\-]{11})      
        (?=[^\w\-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w]*(?:[\'"][^<>]*>| </a>))[?=&+%\w-]*~ix','<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1">YouTube link: $1</a>',$url);
    return $sVideoID;
}

    $hth        = 300; //$_POST['yheight'];
    $wdth       = 500; //$_POST['ywidth'];


?>

<?
//Iframe code

echo htmlentities ('<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$sVideoID.'" frameborder="0" width="'.$wdth.'" height="'.$hth.'"></iframe>');

?>

<?
//Old way to embed code
echo htmlentities ('<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/'.$sVideoID.'" width="'.$wdth.'" height="'.$hth.'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  wmode="transparent" embed="" /></embed>');
}
?>
```

Comment: you might have other parameters in the URL and the order is not deterministic. For example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=g-all-esi&v=6mgFdn4lfrE

Comment: Where are you setting `$sVideoID`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP regex for youtube video id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438544/php-regex-for-youtube-video-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I am wrong, or maybe you haven't included all relevant data, but I do not see anywhere in your code where you execute the function you have created.

Instead of what you are currently doing, try this:

```
echo htmlentities ('<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.getYoutubeVideoID($url).'" frameborder="0" width="'.$wdth.'" height="'.$hth.'"></iframe>');
```

You can't simply define a function and it will execute and assign variables.. what you have has the function, when it is executed, return a variable in it's place.  As an example, you could assign $var the `return value` of your function:

```
$var = getYoutubeVideoID($url);
```

Instead of the very above, you could even try this:

```
$sVideoID = getYoutubeVideoID($url);
```

Lastly, instead of using regex as others have noted, you could use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) in combination with [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get the data from your url:

```
$arr = parse_url($url);
parse_str($arr['query'], $output);
echo $output['v'];
```

Comment: Thank you!, I am new learner to php. But the reason i used regex is that there are many formats for YT URLs. I have tried the `parse_str` but it wasnt sufficient.

Comment: @user1519101 I see then; well, I am happy I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

> How come i am getting no value result for $sVideoID

You never assign it (at least not in the code you provided). The code for `$sVideoID` is inside a user defined function - `getYoutubeVideoID()`. Which you are never calling. **Daedalus** provided a sample resolution in his answer.

**As an aside…** Don't parse the URL with a Regular Expression. There are other, easier ways

For example:

- [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
- [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) or [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) on `query`
- Extract the *video ID*

Comment: As a mention to Daedalus the reason i used regex is that there are many formats for YT URLs. I have tried the parse_str but it wasnt sufficient.

Comment: The fact that the format changes is the main reason a Regular Expression is a poor solution. It's easier to break the URL apart with these functions, and code logic to extract the video ID.